# Is there a CSS entity for the debug icon?

Tags: html, css, icons, entity

Any chance this is available? Every time I search for something of the sort, all of the results are just about debugging css.

[image]

Comment: you have the image, what are you looking for? what are you trying to accomplish that the image doesn't provide?

Comment: Trying to add an icon with CSS content that can be adjusted with CSS. I need to be able to conditionally change the color.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `CSS` entity like the image you've included. As others have commented, since you have the image, you can include it in your CSS via `content`. Another way is to [base 64 encode it](https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64encoder) and add it as a background image.

```css
.bug {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<p>It looks like you have a <span class="bug" aria-label="bug icon"></span>! Do something about it.</p>
```